How can I add height to gradient colors in TailwindCSS?
I know I can add gradient colors like this:

<div class="bg-gradient-to-t from-red-400 via-white to-red-400"></div>`


But how can I limit their height like in CSS?
{
    background-image: linear-gradient(#fff 49%, #F62559 49% 51%, #fff 51%);
}

I couldn't find anything similiar to this. Is it possible?

Yes, it is possible! As per the documentation:

Specifying stop positions
For more control over the gradient color stop positions, combine the gradient color utilities with gradient position utilities like from-10%, via-30% and to-90%.

Thus, the equivalent Tailwind classes for the start and end stops would be from-[49%] and to-[51%] (using arbitrary value syntax).
For the multi-position value for the middle color, we can't seem to do via-[49%_51%] as Tailwind seems to parse this as a color. However, we can work around this by type-hinting the value like via-[length:49%_51%].


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="h-20 grow bg-gradient-to-t from-white from-[49%] via-red-400 via-[length:49%_51%] to-white to-[51%]"></div>

  <div style="height: 5rem; flex-grow: 1; background-image: linear-gradient(#fff 49%, #F62559 49% 51%, #fff 51%)"></div>
</div>



